# QGIS 2.18 - how to plot a new point a certain distance and az from another point

Tags: point, grids-graticules, multipoint

I'm trying to figure out a way to plot a new point (or series of points) along a given az and a fixed interval. Essentially, I'm trying to build a grid for soil sampling.
ty

Comment: What's wrong with the existing grid generators? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried a couple about month ago but they didn't work. Cant remember which ones exactly. Note that this is a costume grid... for example plot a 25 points at 50m intervals along this az from this starting point.